# How to control Scapy sending packets speed?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am using `Scapy` to forge random tcp and udp flows to test packet-in flooding in my SDN experiment. But I don't know how to control `Scapy` sending packets speed. For example, if I want to set `Scapy` sending packets 1000 pkt/s, what should I do ?

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way would be to use scapy’s `sendpfast` together with `tcpreplay` (it must be installed):

```
>>> pkt = Ether()/IP()/TCP()/"blobofdata". # must be layer 2
# let’s send 10000 packets at 1000 packets per seconds
>>> sendpfast(pkt, pps=1000, loop=10000, parse_results=1)
{'packets': 10000,
 'bytes': 660000,
 'time': 9.99,
 'bps': 66006.1,
 'mbps': 0.528,
 'pps': 1000.09,
 'flows': 1,
 'fps': 0.1,
 'flow_packets': 100000000,
 'non_flow': 0,
 'successful': 10000,
 'failed': 0,
 'truncated': 0,
 'retried_enobufs': 0,
 'retried_eagain': 0,
 'command': 'tcpreplay --intf1=enp0s3 --pps=1000 --loop=10000 /tmp/scapyo6ilzjdk',
 'warnings': []}
>>>
```

You even get some stats.
This allows to workaround Python limitations that wouldn’t allow such a high rate of packets.

If you are aiming at lower rates, you could use `inter` from `send`

```
>>> sendp(pkt, count=10000, inter=1./20)  # 20 packets per second
```

Comment: Could you give me a link more specific, maybe I need learn it more specific.

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure what you mean :/ You can use `help(sendpfast)` or `help(...)` most of the time in Scapy

Comment: I mean that how do you know this method. In other words, what books or websites you have read to help you know this.

Comment: You can scroll through both the official doc https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and the source code https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time to understand and find how to send packet in other then eth0 interface. My task was - create UDP Flood. In sendp i could have random udp ports, but with low speed, in this case with sendpfast you can have speed, if you have a good CPU, but only repeat the same packet and this 'Fuzz/RandString' dosent work. 'Parse_reuslts' dosent worked in my case.

```
conf.iface='eth1'
pkt = Ether()/IP(dst="20.20.20.2")/fuzz(UDP())/Raw(RandString(size=1400))
sendpfast(pkt, mbps=1000, loop=50000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I measured the ethernet speed between two nodes using iperf3. I was getting `1.53 Gbytes` while measuring speed with the sendpfast Maximum I got was `58.7Mb` . If you are using sedpfast you may end up getting 26X slower speed. As an information.